# Django Error : when showing two models in one html

Tags: python, django

I want to show 2 models (Input; Result) in one template html(Result):

The error is "ResultView" is not defined. Please correct me if there is anything wrong below. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

**Result - Views.py**

```
from result.models import Result
from inputform.models import Input

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    queryset = Result.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['input'] = Input.objects.all()
        return context
```

**url**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from result.views import ResultView

  urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='dupont'),
    url(r'^input', 'inputform.views.input',name='input'),  
)
```

**result_list---HTML**

```
 <div class="basicinfo">         <!--Input information-->
    {% for input in input_list %}    ------If here correct?
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Company</td>
            <td>{{input.company}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </table>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>

<div class="result">         <!--Result information-->
    {% for result in Result_list %}               ----If here correct?
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Totao</td>
            <td>{{result.Total}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </table>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Found a misspelling in `url(r'^result_list/$',ReultView.as_view(),name='dupont')` It is 'Result' instead of 'Reult'. Also, did you import ResultView in your urls.py?

Comment: Have you imported ListView into your views.py?

Comment: Yeah, I have imported the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misspelling in your `urls.py`. You try to use `ReultView` instead of `ResultView`.
To access the data in you templates you have to use your context names. If you added `Input` objects as `context['input'] = Input.objects.all()`, you need to loop over it in such a way:

```
<div class="basicinfo">
    {% for input_object in input %}
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Company</td>
                <td>{{input_object.company}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Your result_list name is result_list not Result_list:

```
<div class="result">
    {% for result in result_list %}
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Totao</td>
                <td>{{result.Total}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , this is exactly what puzzles me.

Answer (score 1):

You've imported ListView instead of ResultView into your urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to import **ResultView** in **urls.py**
2. You named the **context_object_name** to be **result_list**, when you reference it in **result_list.html**, you should stick to **result_list** instead of using **Result_list**
3. Because you wrote `context[input]=...` this means when you access it in the template, the name of the input list is **input** instead of **input_list** so, you should use:

   ```
   {% for item in input %}
       ...
   ```